# Paste name in scale_fill/color in colorspace does not work in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, color-space

When using **scale_fill_continuous_diverging** from `colorspace` inside a `for loop` or `function` does not paste for the `name` of legend title and through an error as in the example below.

```
library("ggplot2")
library(colorspace)
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(country = LETTERS, V = runif(26, -40, 40))
df$country = factor(LETTERS, LETTERS[order(df$V)]) # reorder factors

    fun_plt<-function(x){
      
      x<-df
      gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = country, y = V, fill = V)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        labs(y = "Under/over valuation in %", x = "Country") +
        coord_flip() + theme_minimal()
      gg
     #Lets say want to paste test in the leged when running through function
      tt<-"test"
  
      gg2<-gg+
        scale_fill_continuous_diverging(name=paste0(tt,"V"),
                                        palette = "Blue-Red 3", l1 = 30, l2 = 100, p1 = .9, p2 = 1.2)
      gg2
    }


fun_plt(df)
```

It works well independently but gives an error when run inside a function.

Comment: Hm. Looks like a bug. Maybe you should raise an issue on the GitHub site. As a workaround you could add your legend label via `labs(fill = paste0(tt,"V"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a problem with the way how the underlying `ggplot2` scale functions (`discrete_scale`, `continuous_scale`, `binned_scale`) were called by the scale functions in `colorspace`. The calling environment was not always preserved and hence the non-standard evaluation of some arguments like `name` did not work as intended.

I have fixed the problem now in version 2.0-1, the current development version of `colorspace` on R-Forge. Installing this should fix the bug:

```
install.packages("colorspace", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Update: Meanwhile this has also been released through CRAN.